# c# cookie key text is getting stripped between the browser call and API endpoint

Tags: c#, cookies, kestrel-http-server, httpcookie, kestrel

.NET core 6

I'm manually creating a cookie (`my:cookie=myValue`) in the Chrome browser to be added to API endpoint call (Tools -> Application -> Cookies -> simply add new line) - then I want to get that key in the .NET and do futher processing.

What is the problem is that something is getting rid of all key text before colon (`:`) character - just the suffix remains.

In the Debug console in .NET I just got:
`cookie=myValue`

It should be:
`my:cookie=myValue`

I've tried to use different browsers, can't log kestrel cookies in console to see if the server is the reason.